# Help hint creation in C# WinForms

Tags: c#

[Image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7efc3b2ddd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7efc3b2ddd.png)

Is there any idea  to create this in C# Windows Application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can't we use like

```
        ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
        t.IsBalloon = true;
        if(textBox1.Text=="")
        t.Show("This value can not be empty", this.textBox1 , 0, -40, 1000);
```

??

Comment: This does *not* look like an answer.  Edit your question and enhance it.

Answer (score 10):

We have a tool tip property of Text Box.Select the Text box press F4 or directly go to the property of Text box->Tool Tip->(Put the Text Whatever you want)This value can't be blank.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "Error Provider" component that you can add to a form, which adds a "Error" property on every control.  It accomplishes a similar goal, but does it a bit differently as far as the visual representation goes.

Answer (score 1):

Propably you need validators to check input forms. these classes are presented in ASP.NET
unfortunatly for winforms you should do it on your own.
for instance there are events of TextBox  Validated and Validating what you can handle to check input data.